# Read database object with spring boot and h2

Tags: spring, hibernate, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa, h2

I want to know how to read database object from h2 database into my spring controller using hibernate (or anything really, I am not married to hibernate).

I have a simple project setup using gradle.

And my `application.properties` is

```
spring.thymeleaf.cache=false
# Datasource
spring.datasource.driverClassName=org.h2.Driver
spring.datasource.platform=h2
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:h2:mem:database
spring.datasource.username=something
spring.datasource.password=password
spring.jpa.database-platform=org.hibernate.dialect.H2Dialect
spring.jpa.show-sql=true
# H2
spring.h2.console.enabled=true
spring.h2.console.path=/h2
spring.h2.console.settings.trace=false
spring.h2.console.settings.web-allow-others=false
# Hibernate
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=none
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.show_sql=false
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.use_sql_comments=false
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.format_sql=false
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.current_session_context_class=org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.SpringSessionContext
```

I can see that schema.sql and data.sql are being executed. And I see my table exists with data inside of it using h2 console. I have an entity object made too.

However I have no idea how I would go about reading my entity object from h2 and into my controller. Can someone point to the right resource or explain how to go about doing it?

Comment: you can read the entity object using CrudRepository from spring-boot-starter-data-jpa. See here https://spring.io/guides/gs/accessing-data-jpa/

Comment: @Devilluminati it doesn't quite explain how I would use it in the controller. My biggest problem is being able to fetch the object in the controller so that I can pass it to the generated webpage.

Comment: so do it in this way https://dzone.com/articles/spring-boot-with-spring-data-jpa. Create repository with entity object as first generic type. Second is long for the ID. Inject this repository in your controller and do what ever you want to do. In MVC you can put the data in a map to read it in the template e.g. thymeleaf. If this does not answer the quest, i did not understand what exactly your looking for.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By far the simplest approach to this is to use [spring-data-jpa](https://spring.io/guides/gs/accessing-data-jpa/). To do this you need an entity (that is, a class with an @javax.persistence.Entity annotation) that will represent a row in your table.

```
@Entity
public class Thing {
    @Id
    private String id;
    private String name;
}
```

Then you need a repository that can read and write from the DB. This is an interface that extends one of the spring repository classes, usually CrudRepository, like this:

```
public interface CustomerRepository extends CrudRepository<Thing, String> {
  Thing findById(long id);
}
```

Then, autowire the repo into your controller's constructor, and you're nearly finished. The last part is calling one of the methods on the repo. You don't have to actually implement the repo, spring will do that for you. The base repo has plenty of useful default methods that you don't even have to list in your code. There are plenty of references for all of this on spring's website and I've linked you to a good tutorial for it (it has gradle examples, but you should really be using maven because it's a lot better in every possible respect).

Comment: have to add that the config class also needs 
`@EnableJpaRepositories(basePackages = {"package.name"})` and
`@EntityScan(basePackages = "package.name")` annotations added, and then everything works.